# Is there something wrong with Bell's inequality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, bells-inequality, locality

Repeating the title because that's what I posted on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/5tp0f2/is_there_something_wrong_with_bells_inequality/) and didn't get an answer. But I guess the proper question is: is there something wrong with the experiment? The text over on Reddit:

> Something has been bothering me for a few days after watching [Veritasium's video on quantum entanglement](https://youtube.com/watch?v=ZuvK-od647c) again, specifically the expected frequency for local hidden information. Can't disagree with the math, but it felt like the premise was wrong for same axis, opposite directions. Accepting the numbers given (if it's supposed to be up in vertical, then it would have preference for a certain alignment at 60°, 3/4 of the time), I drew the expected measurements for a static axis (ignore that most of these aren't actually 60°, apparently it's too hard to split half a circle in 3): https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUOHU.jpg .
>
> Darkened area is where the north of the axis could be located given the first observation. The bottom of the page shows possible positions for the axis when knowing the answer for all 3 directions (it could never be up for vertical, then down for both 60° and -60° for the same particle, since it would need 2 axis, which doesn't make sense for 3d volumes) and what would be determinable by observing 2 particles. When we know a spin to be x in the vertical, we also know it to be 3/4 x at 60°, and 60° happens 2/3 of the time. Isn't this the same [from 07:27](https://youtube.com/watch?v=ZuvK-od647c?t=447) in the video?
>
> So, considering the observations, it seems I reached the same expectation, which would result in the same 50% up or down on average for both inclined detectors when compared to the vertical one. Is there something too crazy here I'm not seeing?
>
> EDIT: If I'm right about this, I might have found a mistake in my page. How can it be that the first split will also make it more likely that the axis would be towards the middle? What happens if 60° is measured first? With non locality it's easy: it just is. But preserving locality and ignoring loopholes, maybe this is only true for the vertical direction. If that's the case, then measuring 60° first, the vertical should still be 3/4, 1/4. But, the opposite 60° should be 5/8, 3/8 since it keeps the whole more likely slice (2/4, or 1/2) and half of one of the more unlikely (1/2 + 1/8 = 5/8) for the same direction.

What I'm claiming is that the >50% difference figure for measurements at (A1,B2 - A1, B3 - B1, A2 - B1,A3) shouldn't be expected because that's not what the experiment is testing. When the results are the same, the axis can be expected to be in one of the two 1/4 possibilities; but when the results are different, it could be either be in the middle (2/4) or one of the sides (1/4) and 2/4+1/4 = 3/4. Then we multiply the odds of choosing a different door (2/3) by the odds of that being the expected spin (3/4) and that's also 1/2, or 50%.

Comment: One should not have to go watch a video in order to undertstand a posted question.

Comment: The answer to the question is that verifying Bell's Inequality is an exercise of elementary algebra, it's been checked countless times, you can check it yourself, and no, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I understand the algebra, I disagree with the assumption that the test is measuring that. You don't have to watch the video, just read my page. If an axis is decided when the entangled particles are created and each particle has an opposite north, then it doesn't matter which direction the first first measurement is, they're perfect mirrors. In the case of 90°, -60°, +60°; when the 1/4 possibility happens for -60° (to know what that is, first a particle must be measured in the vertical), then it couldn't happen for the +60°.

Comment: Just by accepting the axis is more likely to be towards the middle in the vertical position (twice more likely than any of the sides), you can see why the experiment isn't able to meet the algebra. If we were to measure in 3 directions we could, but since we are only measuring in two, there's an uncertainty about the position of the axis when the spin is different for 90° and 60° (it can either be in 2/4 mid, or 1/4 side). It also explains why interactions can break the entanglement, because the particles aren't communicating at all, they just have the same axis and opposite norths.

Comment: Just to emphasize, when they're opposites for 90° and 60°, the axis could be either in the 2/4 mid or 1/4 side; but never in the other side. When they're the same we're locating the axis to be in an specific 60° side cut relative to the vertical; but when they are different, we're locating the axis to NOT be in the 60° cut, instead it could be anywhere in the 120°, but when considering 3 cuts, it's more likely that the axis is in the middle one. Since it can't be in 1/3 side. It can only be in 1/3 mid or 1/3 other side. Weighting it properly, it's 1/4 not side, 2/4 mid, 1/4 other side: 3/4.

Comment: I realized something, the perpendicular line crossing at the 60° inclination makes it so that with a physical axis, 30° should be responsible for 1/4 of the measurements, for each side, while 120° should be responsible for 2/4 of the measurements. It doesn't change the result, just makes the horizontal direction strechted instead and flips everything equally, I'm drawing the corrected version.

Comment: I'm sharing a paper sharing my reasoning in a better way. It's fixed for horizontal preference, but the second image is supposed to be "then B", not "the B" : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By-K-KkcfyO-NFdKV0Vkc2QxR2M/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

This is your mistake:

> When we know a spin to be x in the vertical, we also know it to be 3/4 x at 60°, and 60° happens 2/3 of the time.

You can't just say "A's angle was X therefore B's probability is Y". You're assuming that a measurement of one side will tell you specific information about the other side, but you haven't justified this.

In quantum mechanics the A-angle-predicts-B-angle-then-B-angle-predicts-correlation conclusion is a clear consequence of the underlying math. But that math (i.e. unitary operations applied to state vectors) doesn't apply to classical mechanics, so you need to some other explicit mechanism.

You need to exactly describe what the internal states of the two systems can be. List them off. **Most importantly, say how likely each combination of states is at the start.** Check that, given those likelihoods, Bob getting a measurement B1 is predictive of Alice getting some measurement A2 (or whatever). And finally show that the conditional probabilities match up with the quantum prediction, or at least beat the Bell inequalities. But they won't.

Comment: Why not? I'm just accepting observations. If A's angle is vertical and B's angle is 60°, then B gives opposite spins 3/4 of the time. That's real, I can't disagree with that. I'm not saying the inequality is wrong, as I said in the first paragraph, I'm saying the experiment can't reproduce it. Check what I've answered to the other guy.

Comment: @skafast The point is create a classical model that *predicts* the observation, not a model that *uses* it. Furthermore, because Bell's theorem only applies to models that are local and realistic, you can't just apply the theorem to a model that's simply asserted to behave the same as some experiment. You need to prove the resulting model is local and realistic first.

Comment: @skafast Wait, are you saying the *quantum* prediction is wrong? I thought you were saying the classical prediction matched the asserted quantum one.

Comment: No, I'm saying the quantum prediction is right, but the experiment itself is rigged, it will always break inequality, even if a classical model is considered. Forget the axis likes the horizontal direction more. If we split the particle in 6, then it should be 30° same, 150° different. Bell's inequality says we should expect >5/9 in the experiment, when the actual expectation for the case is 4/5*2/3, which is 8/15. Bell's inequality only works if we measure 3 directions at once. When measuring 2, there's an uncertain range when A1B2 or A1B3 differ.

Comment: All i'm saying is that the experiment can't prove if inequality is happening because it's rigged to break it.

Comment: @skafast In that case my answer is right. You're using an angle rule that classical mechanics can't model, then asserting this shows that classical mechanics matches the quantum predictions. You aren't allowed to use the angle rule in your classical model until you've built something that satisfies the rule using only classical parts, like billiard balls and ropes and pulleys and computers.

Comment: The model doesn't matter. The experiment is used to measure inequality, but it can't measure it. The ones who claim this experiment negates all local hidden information theories say so because they think that such theories should return different values >5/9 of the time (for the vertical, -60, +60) because that's the case when making a matrix with the possibilities for A1B2 OR A1B3. I'm saying that the experiment will always return a value different than 5/9 since it can only measure 2 directions. When knowing 2 opposite to be the same, we know the third, but we don't the third when 2 differ.

Comment: If the experiment is invalid, we can't know that the inequality isn't happening. While breaking the inequality is a way to disprove all local hidden information theories, since the experiment can't really say if inequality is broken or not, then some local hidden theories come back in the realm of possibilities.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with the Bell's inequality, and the experiment and the description in the video. Same axis is no issue due to conservation of angular momentum (mirror image).

However, at relative angle (say 60) while applying Bell's test in the video, all 9 combinations are considered equally likely always, and that is something that has not been verified to the finest levels of details. At least I did not find proper analysis that does so. One can argue that previous outcomes make the subsequent outcomes unequally likely and thus violation of Bell's inequality should not be good enough to prove non-locality of entanglement. This is known as memory loophole which has been closed only at aggregate levels but not at lowest levels of data.